# How to define WinKey shortcut to connect to a paired Bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth, shortcut

I would like to have a short cut, preferred using the WinKey to connect to already paired headset device, instead of opening the setting windows each time I would like to connect my headset.

Comment: I would like the same, but every thing I see requires executables to be downloaded to manage it.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach - do you familiar with one tool that do that?